# catch exceptions thrown by cxf in camel context

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

How can we catch the exception thrown by cxf provider in camel context. I am trying to catch the Mapping exception thrown by ExceptionMapper inside camel context.
this is my catch block.

> ```
> <doCatch>
> <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception> 
>   <handled>
>       <constant>false</constant>
>   </handled>
>  </doCatch>
> ```

but the exception is not getting caught by catch block because the cxf provider (com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider) is throwing the exception and the ExceptionMapper is setting the Response. My requirement is to catch all exceptions in camel context and log them into a database. Is there any way to catch exeption thrown by cxf in camel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onException` block to catch all exception thrown within a `CamelContext`.

```
<camelContext ....>
 <onException>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>

    <handled>
      <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>

    <bean ref="logAction" method="updateErrorStatus" />

    <log message="Exception in camel route!!!" />
  </onException>

  <route ..>
    ..
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

See [camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem because `ExceptionMapper` covers an exception and does not throws it up.

Is it yours `ExceptionMapper` interface implementation?
If so, try in the `toResponse` method re-throw exception as `RuntimeException`

If not create your own `ExceptionMapper` by extending Class which you use and do the same.

UPD: I guess there is no other options

Comment: Yes the ExceptionMapper implementation sets the response instead of throwing it as run time exception.

Comment: So... re-throw it and catch.

Answer (score 0):

The onException sub-route does not handle the exceptions thrown by the JAX-RS json provider within the CXF endpoint.  It only seems to handle exceptions once the Exchange has begun its journey along the route.

To deal with badly formatted json etc, you also need to provide a JAX-RS ExceptionMapper that will return a response directly to the user:

```
@Component(JaxrsExceptionMapper.BEAN_NAME)
class JaxrsExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    static final String BEAN_NAME = "jaxrsExceptionMapper";

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {
        return Response
            .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity(new MyResponseBody(t.getMessage()))
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
    }
}
```

The JAX-RS @Provider annotation doesn't work in Camel.  You need to "name" the ExceptionMapper bean as a provider when you configure your endpoint.  This is along with your JsonProvider bean - which is far from clear in the Camel documentation.

```
from("cxfrs://" + publishedUrl
            + "?resourceClasses=" + MyJaxrsService.class.getName()
            + "&bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer"
            + "&providers=" + JaxrsJsonProviderConfig.BEAN_NAME
                + "," + JaxrsExceptionMapper.BEAN_NAME)
    .to("direct:wherever");
```

For completeness the spring config for a Jackson json provider might be:

```
class JaxrsJsonProviderConfig {

    static final String BEAN_NAME = "jaxrsJsonProvider";

    @Bean(name = BEAN_NAME)
    public JacksonJsonProvider jaxrsJsonProvider(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JacksonJsonProvider(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // optional stuff ...
        mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_ABSENT);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

and your service class might be:

```
public interface MyJaxrsService{
    @POST
    @Path("/myservice")
    MyResponseBody myService(MyPayload body);
}
```

Sorry for re-opening an old topic but this has been hard won knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the exception variable, like this.

```
<doCatch id="_doCatch1">
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <transform id="_transform2">

                    <simple>
                        ${exception.message}
                    </simple>
                </transform>
                <log id="log_exit_exception" message="Error - Exception: ${exception.message}" />
            </doCatch>
```

Comment: I quess, question is not about how to handle caught exception, but how to catch it, since there is  no exception.

Comment: Not an answer to the question